# How to scroll the pdf document using Vscrollbar in C#.net?

Tags: c#, axacropdf

Here i want to scroll the pdf document using vScrollBar in c#.net. i have displayed the pdf document in  axAcroPDF.i want scroll down and up using windows form control(vScrollBar). How can i do it please answer anyone.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code:

```
axAcroPDF1.setViewScroll("FitH", scrollbarValue);
```

Just replace scrollbarValue with the value of your custom scrollbar

Comment: Its working but i can scroll only one page. how can i set or get the value for scrolling full document.